# OCaml: reference cells, Some, None

Tags: ocaml

I am reading the book by Jason, and face the following code.

```
let x = ref None;;
let one_shot y =
    match !x with
        None ->
            x := Some y;
            y
      | Some z -> z;;
```

I do not understand the meaning of `Some` and `None` here.

Answer (score 2):

`None` is something like **is not set** or **null**. if a value matches `None`, this value is not set.

`Some` is something like **is set with something** or **not null**. if a value matches `Some z`, this value has a value `z`.

here, the function `one_shot` looks `!x` (the variable in address `x`). if its `None` then sets with `y` and returns `y` and if is `Some z` then returns `z`

Answer (score 1):

They are constructors of a built-in OCaml datatype, that you could have defined yourself as such:

```
type 'a option =
  | None
  | Some of 'a
```

This means that `None` if of type `'a option` for any `'a`, and, for example, `Some 3` is an `int option`.

Comment: It is a standard-library provided union. It is not as deeply "built-in" as tuples are in case of product types.

Answer (score 1):

Those are constructors for the built-in option type, defined as follows:

```
type 'a option = None | Some of 'a
```

It's a generally useful sum type for representing an optional value, used as such in the example shown in your question.

Worth noting here, it's a built-in type (rather than provided in the `Pervasives` module) because it's used for inference of the types of functions with optional arguments.

For example, consider the following:

```
let f ?x () =
  match x with
  | Some x -> x
  | None -> 0
```

This function has the following type:

```
val f: ?x:int -> unit -> int
```

Comment: Here, in your example it means x is a optional argument. Some x returns x. None returns 0. Since the returned values should have the same type, we have x is int?

Comment: Yup, that's how the type of x will be inferred.